# Por favor no acosar?

Tags: discusión

He notado que hay algunos posts sobre la inactividad del sitio, no creo que acosando a los usuarios sea la forma de lograr que la gente participe.

[Yo postee y una pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/870/por-qu%C3%A9-el-valor-del-textbox-se-restablece-resetea-al-valor-anterior-en-vez-d) hace un tiempo, que nadie supo responderme, logre solucionar el problema (no postee la pregunta sabiendo la respuesta, era una pregunta legitima).

No he tenido tiempo de postear la solucion, si ven mi actividad en SO en general, no ha sido muy alta, porque estoy muy ocupada.

Un par usuarios me mandaron mensajes pidiendo que postee la respuesta, lo cual no me molesta, pero por la forma en que la piden, parece ser que solo quieren que postee la respuesta para que este, no porque la necesitan. Lo cual tampoco esta mal. Pero despues siguen agregando cosas, ahora una bounty con un mensaje:

> Me gustaría ver esa respuesta que el autor ya la tiene pero no ha sido
>   publicada

Como que yo no respondo de capricho.

A pesar de todo esto, no consideraria esto acoso, sino fuera que alguien, sin haber hecho yo ningun cambio a mi post, me sacó un voto a favor y me puso un voto en contra.

Toda vez que yo he tenido una respuesta a una pregunta propia, la he posteado en SO, uno no esta en obligacion de hacerlo, pero lo hago para ayudar a otros. Si no tengo tiempo para postear la respuesta, bien como a mi me gusta, no me parece justo que se me acose de esta manera.  Jamas me paso en SO en ingles y no me da mucho incentivo para que quiera participar..

Pido por favor que aclaren si esto va a ser una practica comun en SO en español. Y por que se ha decido tomar esta dirección.

Comment: Lamento que te sientas acosada. Si quien dio el voto negativo no agrega un comentario no se podrá saber la razón. En relación a la recompensa, quien la ofrece indica que lo hace porque quiere una camiseta, ello en referencia a http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/questions/381/primer-concurso-del-2016.

Comment: @Rubén - El que puso la bounty, es una de las personas que me posteo pidiendo que postee la solucion. Y despues puso que pone la bounty diciendo que tengo la solucion pero no la publique, es practicamente invitar al acoso. Y no es un simple voto negativo, me sacaron un voto positivio que tenia, y me hicieron el voto negativo, sin que yo haya hecho ningun cambio. Y todo eso en las ultimas horas. Eso me parece que califica de acoso.

Comment: @Dzyann yo te vote en contra, ya agregue un comentario

Comment: @Dzyann: Me parece que han habido algunas desafortunadas coincidencias. Como ya han comentado otros, al parecer se trata de un hecho aislado; el acoso no es algo deseable y no creo que quien publicó el comentario y ofreció recompensa en cuestión tuviese la intención de incomodarte. Sirva tu publicación de llamada de atención para la comunidad para sensibilizarnos sobre cómo la combinación de acciones puede provocar la sensación de acoso.

Comment: Wow, un bounty exigiendo respuesta de la autora de la pregunta es un caso novedoso pa mi... y mira que he visto muchas aberraciones aquí en el Stack... antes de abrir el enlace he pensado *"¿a que tiene que ver con las camisetas?"*, bingo¡! Me recuerda las fiestas de barra libre donde por unos petiscos y mojito gratis dejamos nuestra dignidad en el suelo, e igual que en esas situaciones creo que mejor obviar la vergüenza ajena y rezar que nos toque un buen mojito :D

Comment: PS: el título de esta meta-pregunta no me parece constructivo. Si tuviera privilegios de edición lo cambiaria por algo mas descriptivo como `¿Qué hacer cuando un mensaje de recompensa parece ofensivo?`. La norma es: *no atribuyas maldad cuando puede ser ignorancia*.

Comment: @brasofilo - la verdad, no sabia que titulo ponerle, y no estaba segura si era acoso por eso puse "por favor no acosar?" con signo de pregunta. En mi computadora no puedo jamas encontrar el signo de apertura de pregunta :( Mi pregunta iba mas alla de la bounty, por eso no me parece el titulo. Pero si sugieres algo mas general estare feliz de cambiarlo. Gracias!

Comment: @Dzyann si te sentiste acosada por mi parte, te pido disculpas. Mi intención solo fue incentivarte a que publiques la respuesta, compartirla con los demás y de paso otorgarte 50 puntos de reputación. Es todo, no creo que la intención del voto negativo que te dieron fuera por que la persona piensa que no quieres compartir o porque quieres retener la respuesta, de igual manera mi comentario sobre el bounty tampoco fue con esa intención.

Comment: @CésarBustíos - La intencion en general no estaba clara. Al parecer simplemente fue una cadena de hechos desafortunados. Pero la unica forma de saber realmente era preguntar.

Comment: @Dzyann entiendo, al parecer asi fue. Pero "bounty ofensivo" como sugiere brasofilo, para nada.

Comment: @CésarBustíos - Bueno el problema para mi era el conjunto de varias cosas que parecia un acoso, no una parte, por eso no quise poner un titulo que se refiera solo a la parte del bounty. Igual ten en cuenta que gente de diferentes lugar puede interpretar las cosas en diferente forma, y tu mensaje del bounty no me parecia del todo amable. Si le sumas los votos negativos y demas, realmente parecia un ataque. Si solo hubiera estado el bounty, sinembargo, no me hubiera sentido acosada, quizas te hubiera preguntado en un comentario.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yo también lamento que te sientas acosada.  Esto que ha sucedido no es lo normal aquí.  Tu tienes todo derecho de contestar o no a tu propia pregunta.  Si tienes la respuesta y no has podido (o no quieres) responderla, nadie te puede forzar a lo contrario.

Te sugiero que ignores los comentarios negativos y los votos en contra.  Muchas veces los votos en contra se pueden malinterpretar como ataques personales pero rara vez lo son.  Parece que sí hay gente que esta interesada en saber la solución al problema.  No estas bajo ninguna obligación de responder así que toma tu tiempo y no permitas que te molesten los demás.

Esto no es ni será la practica común aquí.

Comment: A mi no me molestan los votos negativos, mas bien que retiraron el voto positivo, pusieron uno negativo, se agrego un bounty y comentarios diciendo que postee, todo de una. No me parece bien. Claramente me votaron negativamente porque no respondi mi propia pregunta a "tiempo".

Comment: Aclaracion, no voy a cerrar mi pregunta, y en cuanto pueda voy a subir la respuesta y demas.

Comment: @Dzyann, Yo te di voto positivo porque la pregunta esta bien formulada (Claridad, formato, ortografía, etc), pero después de analizar tu código me frustré porque algunas cosas no me cuadraron, entonces te di el voto negativo, y el positivo se quito automaticamente

Comment: @Dzyann, no hay que sentirse mal con los votos negativos, son una parte fundamental de Stack Overflow y ayudan a mantener una buena calidad del sitio

Answer (score 6):

Es lamentable que se haya dado una situación así. Mi recomendación para la OP es que lo ignore como un hecho aislado, a menos que sea algo recurrente, y que no por ello disminuya su participación en el sitio.

En lo personal, considero que StackOverflow en español permite y debe permitir la libre participación de las personas, siempre se cumpla con la regla básica de preguntar cosas que tienen una respuesta canónica dentro del tópico, poner esfuerzo cuando se pregunta, y de responder adecuadamente cuando se responde.

Por esa misma razón, y porque me pareció que la pregunta estuvo bien planteada, yo voté a favor de ella cuando la vi por primera vez.

Si ya tienes la respuesta, eres libre de publicarla cuando quieras y puedas.

Puedo agregar que, a nivel personal, considero que es algo así como una regla de cortesía venir a publicarla luego de que se ha pedido algo de ayuda, ya que hay gente que se ha tomado la molestia y el tiempo de leer la pregunta y es una forma de retribuirles con conocimiento. Además de que originalmente se esperaba obtener ayuda de alguien más, y ahora se está en posición de poder proporcionarla uno mismo, yo diría que se está en la obligación moral de hacerlo para las futuras generaciones de búsqueda.

Dicho esto, jamás exigiría que se publique la respuesta y mucho menos que se publique hoy mismo. Considero que eso es una decisión personal de cada participante.

Dicho esto, no he visto una practica generalizada, pero si llegara a serlo, como comunidad se podría pedir un veto para los usuarios que cayeran en la misma. Por ahora es un hecho aislado, pero ya tenemos este hilo dónde se puede obtener retro-alimentación si hay otros usuarios que también pasan por la misma situación.

Comment: Si, estoy de acuerdo, uso SO hace muchos años, mas que nada siempre encuentro lo que necesito en posts ya existentes, y voto. No me gusta postear las cosas asi nomas y es por eso que no postee la respuesta todavia. Pero lo voy a hacer.

Answer (score 0):

Aunque no puedo hablar por nadie,y aunque entiendo el punto de vista de @Dzyann , tambien creo bajo mi punto de vista que se esta llevando esto al extremo, pues creo que todo biene por los siguientes comentarios y el orden de los mismos:

- Usted publica la pregunta y obtinene unos comentarios en el mismo dia
  de formular su pregunta solicitando informacion ect (del 11 de
  diciembre hacia atras)
- despues pasado un tiempo otro usuario pregunta lo siguiente y usted
  responde, (el 5 de enero, imagino que JuanK solo lo pregunto por
  curiosidad)

@Dzyann lograste solucionarlo? – JuanK
@JuanK - Si, solo no he tenido tiempo de postear la respuesta. En la semana lo hago.

---

Ahora creo que es cuando la cosa se "complica" se abre un bounty a la pregunta (quizas el autor de bounty, @CésarBustíos, no se percato de que usted tenia ya una solucion a la pregunta, en el momento de ofrecer la recompensa).Y pasado un rato o dia comenta lo siguiente (quizas fue que de percato de que usted tenia una respuesta)

@Dzyann vamos, queremos ver esa respuesta ;) – César Bustíos

Para ser sincero yo cuando vi el bounty y lei los comentario no estaba el de César Bustíos, pero si en el que usted decia tener una solucion y pense por que se le abre un bounty si ya tiene solucion, pues en los comentarios se menciona, por eso creo que no se percataron que el autor de la pregunta ya lo habia solucionado.

Pero si bien es cierto que usted puede haberse sentido acosado/a, tambien creo que se esta interpretando el mensaje de César Bustíos y "quizas otras coincidencias" (-1 hacia la pregunta ect, que no tiene porque que ser de usuarios implicados en la convesacion), de la forma mas negativa, pues César Bustíos fue el autor de bounty, el que ofrecio la recompensa hacia la pregunta suya, y quizas dejo el comentario citado como diciendo "jo ya que tiene solucion y puse +50 quiero verla" pero no creo que en ningun momento se buscar el acosar al autor de la pregunta para que publicara la respuesta, puede que el mensaje no sea del todo correcto pero si miras el mensaje con buenos ojos creo que veras que no tal como se pinta.

P.D: No digo que no se pueda haber sentido acosada/o, y algunas de las cosas que pongo son congeturas, pero creo que en ningun momento nadie quizo hacerlo/a sentir asi o esa es la percepcion que tengo yo sobre el asunto este, mas que nada lo veo hasta como una broma o toque de humor al decir: @Dzyann vamos, queremos ver esa respuesta ;), ademas la carita te sonrie. Se que lo del acoso es un tema serio, pero no creo que este sea el caso y espero nunca ocurra nada de ese tipo.

P.D: O quizas César Bustíos, queria que publicara la respuesta para verla y asi poder otorgarle la recompensa y que no se perdieran los puntos o volvieran al sistema.

Comment: Pues se puedes interpretar muchas cosas, por mi parte la única intención es entregar el bounty a @Dzyann e incentivar a mostrar la respuesta, espero no ser el acosador. Tu último P.D., eso es lo que pasó, nada más.

Answer (score 0):

Es un hecho que en la comunidad open source en general (considerando Stack Overflow como parte de esa comunidad, puesto que los contenidos tienen licencia CC) hay una parte de la gente que no entiende que cada uno tiene <strike>un nivel de compromiso distinto</strike> unas prioridades y unos compromisos distintos. Hay mil razones para no contestar una pregunta en Stack Overflow: la VidaReal™ se interpone en nuestro camino, tenemos otras prioridades o simplemente no nos apetece. Por tanto a mí no me parece aceptable presionar (mucho o poco) a alguien para que contribuya de alguna forma, no solo porque puede producir el efecto contrario, haciendo sentir mal a la persona, sino porque no tenemos ningún derecho a exigir un trabajo desinteresado y no remunerado. Hay que agradecer todas las contribuciones pero sobre todo respetar la ausencia de contribuciones.

Espero que los moderadores sean serios con este tema y que esto no se convierta en práctica habitual.

Comment: Aunque estoy de acuerdo con tus comentarios en general, no me parece que este sea un tema de nivel de compromiso.

Comment: tienes razón @Dzyann, no se trata de estar más o menos comprometida. he editado mi respuesta para que quede más claro